# Cloudhopper SMPP - How to get messages content which have sent from other clients?

Tags: java, smpp

I have downloaded the source from github from this link: https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp

Assuming I want to test receiving message between clients so I create a server and 2 clients. To run server, I used the command "make server". Then in other machine, a client connected to my server and send 1 message to other client which has phone number "123456" using following code

```
submit0.setSourceAddress(new Address((byte)0x03, (byte)0x00, "654321"));
submit0.setDestAddress(new Address((byte)0x01, (byte)0x01, "123456"));
submit0.setShortMessage(textBytes);

SubmitSmResp submitResp = session0.submit(submit0, 10000);
```

How can the client which has phone number "123456" get message content from phone number "654321"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating sessionHandler like this,

```
DefaultSmppSessionHandler sessionHandler = new ClientSmppSessionHandler();
```

This ClientSmppSessionHandler should be extended to DefaultSmppSessionHandler.
There are 2 listeners.
Please see below example.

```
public class ClientSmppSessionHandler  extends DefaultSmppSessionHandler {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientSmppSessionHandler.class);

public ClientSmppSessionHandler() {
    super(logger);
}

@Override
public void firePduRequestExpired(PduRequest pduRequest) {
    logger.warn("PDU request expired: {}", pduRequest);
}

@Override
public PduResponse firePduRequestReceived(PduRequest pduRequest) {
    PduResponse response = pduRequest.createResponse();
     logger.info("SMS Received: {}", pduRequest);
     if (pduRequest.getCommandId() == SmppConstants.CMD_ID_DELIVER_SM) {
         DeliverSm mo = (DeliverSm) pduRequest;
         int length = mo.getShortMessageLength();
         Address source_address = mo.getSourceAddress();
         Address dest_address = mo.getDestAddress();
         byte[] shortMessage = mo.getShortMessage();
         String SMS= new String(shortMessage);
         logger.info(source_address + ", " + dest_address + ", " + SMS);
     }
     return response;
}
```

}